# If I am creating generic "Meet our team" page, how to know the clicked contact button belongs to which team member?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a "Meet our team" page and it is generic and getting its data from a database. This page is checking if there is still a team member in the database, if so, it creates a div for this team member, the div has the following: picture, name, description and contact button. So, the number of Divs it creates is unknown it depends on the number of team members in the database. When a user clicks on one of the "contact" buttons, I want to know the clicked button belongs to which team member. How can this be done. My page is developed using PHP, CSS, HTML and Javascript.

This is my PHP code:

```
 <div class="row_team">
            <?php
                while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {  
                    if($i %3 == 0)
                    {
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row_team">
                <?php }             
            ?>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="card_team">
                    <img style="
                    /*width:100%;*/
                    max-width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                    ">
                    <?php echo('<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['photo'] ).'" />')?>
                    </img> <br><br>
                    <div class="container_team">
                        <h2 id="teamMemberName" style="color:rgb(85,55,72);"><?php echo($row['name'])?></h2>
                        <p class="comment more" style="color:rgb(64,120,43);"><?php echo($row['bio'])?></p>
                        <p><button class="btn btn-secondary button_team" onclick="modalOpen()">Contact</button></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            $i++;
                }?>
```

When the user clicks on contact a box is opened but this is not my question I want to be able to know the clicked button belongs to which team member

Comment: Add an attribute to the button with the team member ID. `<button class="contact" data-member="1">Contact</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use dataset

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target}) => {
  if(target.matches('button')) {
    const { dataset: { id }} = target;
    alert(`You selecgted ${id}`)
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Member 1</p>
  <button data-id="1">Contact</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Member 2</p>
  <button data-id="2">Contact</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Member 1</p>
  <button data-id="3">Contact</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In your above example you know previously that you have three divs and which team memebr is in which div. What should I do if I don't know both?

Comment: yes, but this works when the number of DIVs is previously known. However, I am talking about the case where the number of DIVs is determined dynamically. Anyway, I already found a solution using Javascript. Thanks

Comment: The above javascript does not need to know how many divs, it works against any.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I solved the problem in a similar way but using id of the button instead of data-id.  Thanks